# how to compile/build android aapt on new platform?

Tags: android, build, compilation, aapt

I'd like to recompile android **aapt** for debian **amd64** platform. We can have the [source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=tools/aapt;h=89c06bbbe971d68486c39fa2ef5000399032f1e9;hb=HEAD) on git but I don't understand how to compile it. There is a simili makefile (Android.mk) which seems not to be complete and dependant to others.

There is a Makefile in [build.git/core](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/build.git;a=tree;f=core;h=280857f3ad10d6bfda80ac7ac4e31cf1a89501be;hb=HEAD). Do i need to get all the android source code to recompile only aapt ? I'd prefer to only recompile this tool but if I need to compile complete sdk, tell me. Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Get android source following instructions here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading

Step 2: Setup environment: `source build/envsetup.sh`

This adds a number of useful commands to your env.

Read more here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building

Step 3: Run `mmm /frameworks/base/tools`

This will selectively build all the tools, including `aapt` as well as it's dependencies. This is much faster than building everything in android.

Aapt has been replaced by aapt2 since this question was asked. The binary will be located in `out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt2` when building on Linux. Replace `linux-x86` with your os.

Answer (score 0):

i compiled the code once.
Once you have finished downloading the code follow the build instruction under:
[android source site](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) which are basically run `. build/envsetup.sh` and

> $ lunch full-eng

and then simple

> $ make

which will build everything including the tools.
If i'm not mistaken make sdk used to build the sdk only, but i'm not sure if it's still applies
The issue is that it's not amd64' that's the hot the output most likly will still be linux32, the question i don't know myself is how to cross build for other platform such as win32\win64\mac\linux64 out of them i know for sure that win32\mac are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Do it Tom Arn's way:
https://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/source/checkout

The aapt source code, all by itself (without the entire android source)is here: http://java-ide-droid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jni/aapt/

His modifications to the original source are in the README.

Comment: Links are dead. I think this answer should either be updated or killed.

Comment: links are dead, could you update them? :(